# Difference Between reinterpret_cast Usage

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Are these two cast statements the same? They produce the same results.

```
const std::int16_t i =  3;
char a[ 2 ];

*reinterpret_cast<std::int16_t*>(a) = i;
reinterpret_cast<std::int16_t&>(a)  = i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because of the implicit array-to-pointer conversion.

The first attempts to cast a pointer; so the array is converted to a pointer (to its first element) to allow that cast. Then you dereference the pointer, to write over the array's bytes.

The second casts a reference to the array into a reference to an integer; assignment to that reference again writes over the array's bytes.

If you were to try this with a non-array type, the first wouldn't compile; you'd have to explicitly take the address, `&a`, before casting that pointer.

Comment: Why does reinterpret_cast<std::int16_t&>(a) even work? a is of type char* (since char a[] is only syntactic sugar), and I wouldn't think reinterpreting a pointer as a reference is a good idea. Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: @Daerst: No, `a` isn't `char*`, and an array isn't "syntactic sugar". `char[2]` is an aggregate type containing two bytes; the cast reinterprets those bytes (not a pointer) as a two-byte integer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, seems I had some misunderstanding there.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - Thanks Mike. A co-worker says the reference is safer, but I don't think it is.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: After thinking about it, I think I got confused about `char[2]` and `a[i]`. The latter is indeed (please correct me if wrong) the same as `*(a + i)`, which implies that `a` itself is a pointer. This very thing that is used as a pointer here is reinterpreted as a reference above, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Daerst: It is indeed the same as `*(a+i)`, but that doesn't imply that `a` is a pointer. It's implicitly convertible to a pointer, via the standard array-to-pointer conversion I mentioned in the answer. That conversion doesn't happen if you cast the array to a reference type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: My bad, I should have read more carefully. Thank you!